# Ajax Chatting ( Loading Messages ) repeated more than one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I designed a chat room using ( Ajax , jquery , PHP , mysql )

but when someone send a message to another the message repeated 4-5 times ,

I'm using this code ( jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
               $.ajax({
                  url: 'getChatting/182/212',
                  success: function(data) {
                    $('#messages').prepend(data);
                  } 

              });
             }, 1000); // ervery 1 second the message box refresh to loading new message
          });
      </script>
```

// php code laravel

```
public function getChatting($from_id , $to_id){
    $ListChat = DB::table('cht_messages')
                ->where('user_from_id',$to_id)
                ->where('user_to_id',Auth::user()->id_user)
                ->where('readit_message',0)

                ->join('main_users','main_users.id_user','=','cht_messages.user_from_id')
                ->select('cht_messages.content_message','cht_messages.id_message' , 'main_users.display_name_user')
                ->orderby('cht_messages.created_at')
                ->get();

            DB::table('cht_messages')
            ->where('user_from_id',$to_id)
            ->where('user_to_id',Auth::user()->id_user)
            ->update(array('readit_message'=>1));
    $messages = '';

    if(Count($ListChat) > 0):
        foreach($ListChat as $message) {

            $messages .= '<span id="cht_auther" style="color:red;">'.$message->display_name_user.'</span>
                <span id="cht_date">01-01-2014</span>
                <span id="cht_spr"> : </span>
                <span id="cht_cnt">'.$message->content_message.'</span>
                <br clear="both"/>

                ';
        }
    endif;
    return $messages;

}
```

but it will repeate a message more than 6 or 7 , and php code it will take the last message which not read ...

I'm sorry for my bad english

Thanks

Comment: share the php (getChatting) page too & the required HTML

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` to the beginning of your `success` function to verify the PHP isn't returning duplicate messages. Or check Network in your Dev Tools.

Comment: At least you should check if the message already loaded to a chat. And please show your php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create chats I use have PHP pass a JSON array back to my Javascript with all the normal information and a unix timestamp. When I am looping through that array I check the timestamp. When the page is loaded I have a variable called something like `lastMessage` and everytime I loop through messages I check if the message timestamp is `>lastMessage`, if it isn't then I don't display it to the user and then update `>lastMessage` with the timestamp of that message. If you come across the issue of users posting messages at the same second then use `microtime()` instead of `time()` for timestamps.

https://www.php.net/microtime